# How to set path to a json file in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with defining the path to the static json file that is located inside the App_data folder in my MVC 5 web application.
I use javascript code that loads openstreet map in a web application . The map should load polygon(on a new layer) whose coordinates are written within the json file.
When I run the web application inside the Chrome browser and start the developer console , receive the following error:

**GET localhost:51548/Home/parcel1.GeoJSON 404 (Not found)

    b.send

    (anonymous function)**

I was looking for similar problems on the internet. One way was to configure/add the mime type(json) in IIS , but still the same error.
Whichever way i define the path to the json file, still the same error occurs.
Other solution is to add mime type inside system.Webserver tag in Web.config file, but still the same error occurs.
Within _Layout.cshtml file I added the javascript code, and part of that should add that layer (polygon) on the map is:

```
var = new parcel1 OpenLayers.Layer.Vector ( " parcel1 GeoJSON " , {
                protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP ( {
                    url : " parcel1.GeoJSON "
                    Format : new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON ( )
                } ) ,
                strategies : [
                    New OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed ( )
                ]
            } ) ;
            map.addLayer ( parcel1 ) ;
```

For hours im trying to find solution for that problem.

Comment: What is at the endpoint `/Home/parcel1.GeoJSON`? The request is being routed to the default route. Is this intended? What does your HomeController look like?

Comment: endpoint is the parcel1.GeoJSON file. No, i don't know  why is being routed to the default route. Inside my HomeController i have Index and Parcels method  which returns view.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the endpoint is /Home/Parcels and then loaded map, without polygon (parcel1.GeoJSON is not found)

Comment: It is using the default route because you are requesting `"parcel1.GeoJSON"` from the root of the server. MVC checks for a controller literally named `"parcel1.GeoJSONController"` if the file with that exact name doesn't exist it assumes you meant to use the default route which is `/Home/{action}/{id}.`

Comment: I am relatively new to MVC; how can I avoid it?

Comment: Avoid what? routing of your requests? You can try writing out the full URL. ASP.NET will ignore a URL that matches the location of a physical file. Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#scenarios_when_routing_is_not_applied

Comment: Sorry, i thought how to fix it